# Circular motion and inclined friction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction

I'm given the following picture: [image]

> A car with the mass *m* passes the top of a hill with the height *H*.
>   The coefficient of friction is $µ$. The speed of the car is
>   $v_0$ in the moment of braking. The incline is described by
>   $α$ in the figure, and its curvature is $3H/2$. Find the acceleration of the car in the moment of braking.

I've calculated that the normal force is $N = mg - (2v^2/3H)$

Since $F_f = µN$ it's tempting to say that $F_f$ is equal to $µmg -  (2v^2/3H)$ but leaving out the angle leads me to believe I'm missing something.

Sketch of the problem:

[image]

Comment: >Find the acceleration of the car in the moment of braking.

I'm unsure if my lazy F_f = µN solution is correct, given it's on an incline.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I sketched up something in photoshop to help illustrate where my problem stems from. [link](http://i.imgur.com/t1W5hoN.png) It doesn't make sense to me that the normal force would be smaller than the perpendicular component of mg.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why do you think that

> It doesn't make sense to me that the normal force would be smaller than the perpendicular component of mg

Yes, it is, because the ground is bending away below the car. If it would bend quicker the car would be flying and there would be zero normal force.

No, it's okay. The normal force would be $mg\cos\alpha$ without the curvature, and substracting the curvature you get the new normal force - and from this the friction. That's okay.

But be aware, that there are two components of the acceleration: one tangential from $F_f$ and also the radial you calculated ($2v^2/3H$). You have to add them (with Pythagoras, if you want to have the magnitude of the net acceleration).

So you see, it's not too easy, and you will use the angle and the curvature...
I hope you can understand this sketch of a solution? :)

Comment: Interesting, and a very good explanation too.

Comment: also, sorry to bug you more, but would you say this is somewhat accurate? http://i.imgur.com/pr3Mxa5.png Where green is the net acceleration and pink is the tangential one from Ff. Pink is at an angle, alpha.

Comment: No, two missing points: 1) the radial acceleration goes inwards, not outwards. you can see this from your forces too - the force up is *lessened* by the radial term; you have to accelerate inward to bend along the circle, you would stay on the tangent else  2) you're still missing the $\cos\alpha$ in the $F_N$, but that's maybe a "typo".